Use greek letters not as part of a math equation
If I would like to use Greek letters not as part of math equations but to write quotations or other Greek text in my otherwise English work, how can I do that?

See the babel package supports a number of languages.  You just have to switch the language on and off.

and ensure an appropriate font is loaded.

using lualatex, you can mix English and Greek texts:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts]{greek}
\babelfont{rm}{DejaVu Sans}
\babelfont[greek]{rm}{FreeSerif}

\begin{document}
   Hello -- Καλημέρα
\end{document}


With pdftex:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

English \foreignlanguage{greek}{ελληνικά} English.

\end{document}

